# Как передать post параметры в http.client Angular

Tags: http, angular2, angular, angular4, httpclient

С чём может быть связано, что angular httpClient не шлёт post параметры?
Сразу скажу- документацию я читал.
Сервер на php и при тесте через Postman и средства отладки принимает post параметры.
Я сделал даже вывод всех post параметров, но вот только angular почему-то их не шлёт.

```
public urlapi = 'http://localhost:81/api.php';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };

public GetOrders(): Observable<[]>{
        const postBody = {'param': 'value'};
        return this.http.post(this.urlapi, postBody , this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(data => {
          return data.map((element: any) => {
              return {id: element.Id};
          });
}));
```

Я хочу сосчитать на сервере эти параметры, но вижу пустой список параметров, которые я вывожу `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

В чём может быть дело, если бекенд рабочий и выводит данные? я перерыл пол дня кучу документации и не разберусь. Это с заголовками не может быть связано?

Comment: а вы попробуйте прочитать через поток file_get_contents('php://input')

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем странно, но так заработало

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('picture', file);
formData.append('OrderId', this.ordersService.SelectedOrder['Id']);
```

и formData  подставляю

```
return this.http.post(this.urlapi, formData , this.httpOptions)
```

А вот так - не работало, хотя везде в интернете написано так `const formData = {'param': 'value'};`